# How to describe in TS a recursive object with only-string keys?

Tags: typescript

I want to describe in terms of types an arbitrary object which can have only `string` (e.g. not `symbol`) keys **on each nesting level**.

So I want something like this (the example doesn't work and isn't even valid):

```js
type RecursiveRecord = {
  [key: string]:  
    RecursiveRecord[key] extends object ? 
      RecursiveRecord :     // a nested object, apply the same keys restriction
      RecursiveRecord[key], // just a non-object value
}
```

Is there any way I can achieve my goal?

Thank you.

**P.S.**
Maybe (see the comments) my question can also be formulated as «How to describe the type which is the opposite of `object`?». Because in that case, I could write something like this: `type RecursiveRecord = { [key: string]: Not<object> | RecursiveRecord };`.

Comment: `type RecursiveRecord = { [key: string]: string | RecursiveRecord };`

Comment: @caTS Thanks! But your approach requires explicitly describing all possible values (non-object) types in the object. What if I have a value in the object whose type isn't `string` but `number`? I'd like to avoid such explicitly describing.

Comment: Are you looking for [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WoA2LN) perhaps? Where you define a `Primitive` type? (Please mention @jcalz to notify me if you reply)

Comment: @jcalz Yes, something like your playground example but I'd strongly like to avoid manually describing the `Primitive` type.

Comment: Strongly? Can you articulate why that matters? TypeScript doesn't have negated types so there's no `not object` you can write: `Exclude<unknown, object>` doesn't work because `Exclude` only filters unions and `unknown` isn't a union.  What, in particular, is the problem with defining `Primitive` somewhere and using it?  Any alternative I can imagine is going to be more complicated (e.g., a generic type with a helper function to make inference possible).

Comment: @jcalz I want to avoid writing the `Primitive` (or, more commonly, `Value`) type because it will be necessary to add new union items to the union if `RecursiveRecord` with new values' types will appear. However, @caTS made a very good point about functions, arrays, maps, etc, etc being objects too. I probably want a `JustPlainObject` type, but I understand it probably goes beyond the TS abilities (primarily due to the JS nature).

Comment: @jcalz Maybe you will edit the answer and add a separate union `Primitive` type in its example, so I could with a clear conscience accept the answer and commend you both.

Comment: Wait, you want me to edit @caTS's answer? (Probably not going to do that unless caTS wants me to)  Or write my own?

Comment: @jcalz Well, I thought about editing the existing answer. I believe this is common practice on SO, isn't it?

Comment: It is common enough but I don't feel comfortable making substantial edits (as opposed to fixing a typo) to someone's answer, especially if there's a good chance they are still around to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we use a generic type, we can describe a recursive record that uses this generic type:

```
type RecursiveRecord<T> = { [key: string]: T | RecursiveRecord<T> };

type RecursiveStringRecord = RecursiveRecord<string>;
```

Comment: Thank you for the additional example! But still, it's necessary to define the type of the values — now as the generic parameter. That's why I wrote «an arbitrary object».

Comment: @shau-kote Do functions count as objects? What about arrays? Maps, sets, regex, dates? Or do you *only* want primitives?